# как преобразовать сам кортеж в строку?

Tags: python, строки, преобразование, кортежи

у меня есть кортеж

```
('8', '9', ':', ';')
```

можно ли как нибудь вернуть в переменную этот кортеж как строку?
тоесть

```
a = "('8', '9', ':', ';')"
```

Comment: `a = repr(кортеж)`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
tup = ('A', 'B', 'C')
print(type("" + str(tup)))
```

Вернёт строку (<class 'str'>)

Реализация вашего варианта:

```
tup = ('8', '9', ':', ';')
print("" + str(tup))
```

Comment: А зачем автору вопроса строка `<class 'str'>`?

Comment: Добавил, дабы показать какой класс возвращает.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Добавил реализацию задачи юзера.

Comment: конкатенация с пустой строкой не нужна, если используется конвертация в строку.